# What UBUNTU iso do I use for my Old Powerbook G4 Mac, 17 " 1.33 with Radeon

Tags: mac, powerpc

I already tried LUBUNTU, but that was no better than tiger since firefox is not supported and I cant get videos to play or sound on the computer. At least with mac os I have all that.

I am really trying to get UBUNTU on the Power PC. I like how it works on my other devises. At the very end I just want to dual boot it or run it off a usb.

PowerPC 7447/7457altivec supported

Please help me get my old mac some functionality back. It was a great machine.

tried ubuntu-12.04-desktop-powerpc.iso  it installed LUBUNTU well its the desktop environment
tried 13.04  no luck. 
Well I just checked bios and its running Saucy Salamander.

thank you

Comment: Firefox isn't supported? What? Try opening the terminal and typing `sudo apt-get install firefox`. If it's not available for PowerPC in the standard repos, though, then changing *buntu derivatives is not going to fix that. If you're feeling up to the task, you can try Googling "compile firefox debian", the second result (from HowtoForge) is rather useful...

Comment: Firefox may have been called ice-weasel.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have sorted this by now, but Lubuntu is less painful because it it does not seem to rely on radeon.

I am assuming you have ATI Radeon not NVidia GPU.

Once Lubuntu is installed, you can install gnome and unity but it is not quite perfect - for example login screen remains in a Lubuntu configuration.

I have used several, latest being 13.04.

On booting live CD you will need to use

```
live video=radeonfb:1024x768-32@60
```

You can try other resolutions, depths and refresh rates to suit your machine.

For 17" PowerBook G4 it should be

```
live video=radeonfb:1440x900-24@60 or 
live video=radeonfb:1440x900-32@60
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here is the answer. I'm not kidding it took a while and it was not pain free. But my basic steps were. Find an 10.4 Ubuntu ppc disk. I booted from that. What was not working was the wireless so I had to Ethernet from my computer. Right away Ubuntu wipes the disk and begins loading. 
What is weird is I think I downloaded the server disk by mistake. It took forever to load, but I did have to use the live command to get it to boot. And the actual command was not Radeon 1024x 768@60 but instead change the refresh to @75.

Next I had to figure out how to change this from a server to a single computer reboot. I stuck in the 10.10 disk and looked up a command to install unity. It does this rather quickly, but it is live and the connection get stuck. Just unplug the ethernet connection if the disk is spinning and it will find libraries from the cd. 
The next step is finding the 12.04 disk. That also provides the driver to get the internet working. Now if your like me you have an extra usb modem hanging around which works great but it take about 100 trials to get the hardware to recognize the airport card. Eventually it all works out. 
Then there you are, wireless, desktop can find apps, and then maybe if your lucky your sound comes works right away. But aha. Flash is not working with Firefox and you can kiss watching pretty much any video goodbye. 
Until you search and find flash.com which gives you linux drivers you install and voila, you finally have a working computer. It all works although you then wonder what the heck good is this? Simultaneously, you find web browsers that promise to work with tiger and leopard. So is Ubuntu a great install on PPC? IM not sure. It does seem to crash a bit, as the machine is ten years old. But then everything is up to date. And I do get to play [Galaga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaga) on it, where I never could with the Mac OS (stupid emulators!)

Anyways. I am thinking Dual boot or just get rid of Ubuntu as maybe a web browser would give this old box more functionality and the drive would spin all the time. It is probably a little memory slow for even Ubuntu (as it screamed with Lubuntu on it), But it also shows that Ubuntu has a great place on a more modern mac, which I have triple booted and typing this for you. Gosh I'd rather use Ubuntu than the new stupid windows, which locks you into single screen applications at a time and then limits your functionality . But Ubuntu on this iMac is screaming fast and a pleasure to work with. Heck its even fast on my Intel 6 year old pc, which it also brought new life too.

So my next post will be suggestions how to add back tiger to be able to dual boot the powerpc, Otherwise, its just a novelty and I would get rid of it on that older machine. 
Over all I am loving Ubuntu, thanks to all you developers!